# Can the cryptographic algorithm DES be implemented in a electromechanical machine with the technology of the early 20th century (1900-1938)?

Tags: alternate-history

Can the cryptographic algorithm DES be implemented in a electromechanical machine with the technology of the early 20th century (1900-1919)?
The machine must have the following requeriments:

1. Must no be bigger than a desk.
2. Must have at least 50 characters per minute of capacity.
3. Every unit must have a maximum price of 10 000 Reichsmarks.
4. Is valid have a modified DES, to work with characters instead of bits.

## Important Note

With technology of 1900-1938, I refer to only using something that can be orders to a professional electromechanical enginer of that epoch, giving him the blueprints and the money.

Comment: How much money? Something that might use vacuum tubes by the tens of thousands cannot be handled by a single engineer. But with sufficient funds, that engineer could hire assistants. Also, would it be OK to fund a new production line for parts?

Comment: @o.m. max 10 000 Reichmarks per unit, and is okay to production lines, because is intended to be used in the Kriegsmarine.

Answer (score 6):

An informal analysis says probably yes but it would be as expensive as the [Z3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z3_(computer)) or [ENIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) and it would not be particularly fast.

Going by the description and walkthrough of DES [here](https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Ekant/teaching/hess/krypto-ws2006/des.htm), the bulk of the operations are permutations and [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).  From the hardware perspective, static permutation is just a matter of wiring and XOR can be implemented using relays as shown [here](https://tams.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/applets/hades/webdemos/05-switched/20-relays/xor.html) or vacuum tubes.  The 16 iterations can be handled by feeding results back through the same circuit 16 times instead of implementing all 16 iterations in hardware.

Comment: Yes, so basically for 1938 DES encryptor/decryptor would be a non-mobile "state of the art" computing machine.

Answer (score 0):

With the qualification given by the OP in the comment, I believe not. The [Volksempfänger VE301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksempf%C3%A4nger) was 76 Reichsmark, and it contained three vacuum tubes. This gives a price of roughly 25 RM per installed tube. Assuming a similar price per installed tube, the OP could afford perhaps 400 tubes and supporting hardware. [ENIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC) had 18,000 tubes. This leads me to assume that 400 tubes are not nearly enough.

(I'm assuming that final costs are proportional to the number of tubes, with all the other wires, resisitors, transformers, etc. in proportion to the tubes. That's a wild guess, but any efficiency of scale by the larger installation would be balanced by heat management and reliability issues. It is also assuming a large production run rather than one-off prototypes.)

<s>But the comment also mentions the Kriegsmarine as a potential user. That's relevant because the Nazis **could** have employed an one-time-pad system for communication between ship and shore (the shore installation stores all pads, each ship or sub gets a distinct copy) and between prearranged *wolfpacks* (each sub in a flotilla gets a copy of the same block). And also because the U-Boat war wasn't doomed *just* because of breaking the Enigma, [Huff-Duff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-frequency_direction_finding#Battle_of_the_Atlantic) and radar on patrol aircraft also mattered. Perhaps I'm guessing the intent of the question wrong, but [Kurier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurier_system) plus knowledge of what the Poles and Turing were up to might do the job.</s>

Comment: As Grumpy said, you do no need vacuum tubes. And yes, you are guessing very wrong.

Comment: @Erdel, I'm not sure if relays would be any cheaper ... regarding the guess, well, it is a common *what if*.

Comment: What about complety mechanical XOR gates like the ones here: https://www.randomwraith.com/logic.html?

Comment: @Erdel, my *gut feeling* is that those would be not substantially easier/cheaper than relays or vacuum tubes. There are reasons why first tubes and then transistors made the race.